# If function with multiple criteria to return answer based on that criteria?

Tags: excel

I couldn't find a similar question to this so I apologize if someone has asked this before.

What I have are three string options.  Let's call them "A", "B", & "C".  One of these three string options will appear in cell A1.  What I am hoping to do is, based on what is in A1, return a set number that corresponds to the three strings in B1.

The corresponding values would be: A = 1, B = 2, & C = 3

I've tried the LOOKUP function below without any luck.

=LOOKUP(A1,{"A","B","C"},{1,2,3})

Any ideas on a formula that will do this correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: how exactly it's `without any luck`? formula works for me

Comment: I apologize, my example did not match my actual criteria.  It was not in alphabetical order which was the issue.  Also, Barry's answer below has opened up a few more possibilities for calculating the values I want.  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LOOKUP` needs the strings to be listed in alphabetical order....and you may get a "closest match" (e.g. in your sample formula if A1 contains "Z" formula returns 3) , better with `VLOOKUP`, `HLOOKUP` or `INDEX/MATCH`, e.g.

`=INDEX({1,2,3},MATCH(A1,{"A","B","C"},0))`

or

`=HLOOKUP(A1,{"A","B","C";1,2,3},2,0)`

or better still - list all strings in one range, e.g. `Y2:Y4`, and list the corresponding return values in the next column, `Z2:Z4` and use `VLOOKUP` like this

`=VLOOKUP(A1,$Y$2:$Z$4,2,0)`

Comment: +1, also this one possible: `=LOOKUP(2,1/(A1={"A","B","C"}),{1,2,3})`

Comment: I did not know I could use Index/Match like that!  Thank you for the help and the great explanation!!!